# Why total frame count is different in ffmpeg than ffprobe?

Tags: ffmpeg

I wanted total frame count of video so that i use below ffprobe command :

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_frames -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 100P.mp4
```

and i get output below

[image: output of ffprobe]

in above output i get `559 frames`

then i use same video to add watermark on it and i use below command:

```
ffmpeg -i 100P.mp4 -i mt.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -codec:a copy -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

i get output like this:

[image: output of ffmpeg]

and in above image, after adding watermark i get `605 frames`

so my question is why i am getting different frame count in ffmpeg and ffprobe?

Comment: Just FYI: x264 `-preset ultrafast` is only a bit fast but *much* worse quality (per bitrate) than `-preset veryfast`.  That's the fastest preset you should normally consider for anything except lossless `-qp 0`. (And x264 is so fast that you should normally use at least `medium` if not `slower` or `veryslow`).  Ultrafast is so bad that even with high bitrate you get ugliness.  If you need to disable CABAC, B-frames, and/or 8x8 DCT for some reason, do that with profile `main` or `baseline`, not by destroying your video quality as well with `subme=0`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

FFmpeg, by default, sets constant frame rate mode for MP4 output. When the input stream is VFR, ffmpeg will duplicate or drop frames to generate a CFR stream. In the output stats, to the right of `frame=605`, you can see `dup=46`, which indicates that ffmpeg added 46 duplicated frames. The short version is this happens when two input frames are further apart than `1/FPS` seconds, where FPS represents the output frame rate.  The output frame rate is set to the detected input framerate (the `tbr` value), if not expressly set by the user.

Add `-vsync vfr` to prevent frame duplication.

Comment: shouldn't you use `-vsync passthrough` to get the exact number of frames as reported by ffprobe?

Comment: Yes, you should but those could include frames with identical timestamps. `-vsync vfr` will drop those.

Comment: and when vfr drop those, i guess it will no longer match the number of frames as reported by ffprobe

Comment: Correct. The OP is about why the counts are different, now how to get them to match :). My vsync statement is just a tip to avoid increasing count.

Comment: Whenever you set `-vsync vfr` (and you pretty much always want to set that) you might also want to set `-enc_time_base -1`, otherwise ffmpeg screws up the presentation timestamps.