# Frame export for VFR video failing with -vsync passthrough option

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a VFR video for which I am trying to extract all frames to .jpg's.

Applying `ffprobe -i Video_Stream_0.mp4 -print_format json -loglevel fatal -show_streams -count_frames -select_streams v` shows me there are 7,387 frames in total:
[Frame Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdswj.png).

Applying `ffmpeg -i Video_Stream_0.mp4 -vf vfrdet -an -f null -` tells me how bad the VFR is:
[Lots of VFR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zSxW.png).

The output generated with that command may provide a clue to the future problem: [A clue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chAKw.png)
It's a little bewildering to me that the earlier line reports an average frame rate of 6.02 fps while the later reports 6 fps.

Applying `ffprobe -show_frames -of compact=p=0 -select_streams v:0 -f lavfi "movie=Video_Stream_0.mp4" > Output_Data.txt 2>&1` aggregates all the frame information. Frame 66 will be the problematic one, although I don't see anything pathological about the pts or dts: [Frame 66 info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goNAk.png).

The only thing unique about Frame 66 is that it has the shortest duration, coming in hot with a 32 ms duration: [Frame 66 has 32 ms duration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB5ra.png). Here I have sorted all frames by duration. The frame with the longest duration is 0.504 seconds, while most hover around 1/6 seconds per frame.

When applying `ffmpeg -i Video_Stream_0.mp4 out-%03d.jpg` File Explorer says I have a folder with 7,364 .jpg's, 23 frames less than I expect. Yet the first file in the folder is out-001.jpg and the last file is out-7363.jpg, so perhaps there is one duplicate, or File Explorer is buggy. A clue is found in the ffmpeg output: [Frame export clues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP4tl.png).

We see dup=3 and drop=27. According to this thread: [Why total frame count is different in ffmpeg than ffprobe?](https://superuser.com/questions/1512575/why-total-frame-count-is-different-in-ffmpeg-than-ffprobe) dup happens when there are two frames that are more than 1/FPS seconds apart. Looking at my Excel file, I have way more than 3 frames that are spaced far longer than 1/6.02 seconds per frame, so that doesn't make much sense. But the numbers add up in terms of 7,387 (expected) - 27 (dropped) + 3 (duplicated) = 7,363 frames.

Applying `ffmpeg -i Video_Stream_0.mp4 -vsync vfr outVFR-%03d.jpg` gives me 7,359 frames. Not sure why not 7,360 since it is supposed to not duplicate.

Finally, the command `ffmpeg -i Video_Stream_0.mp4 -vsync passthrough outVSYNCPass-%03d.jpg` gives me all the stills including frame 66 and then quits: [Conversion Failed!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uzp1.png).

So, how can I get out all 7,387 frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MJPEG encoder is fussy about colliding PTS.

Just retime all frames.

```
ffmpeg -i Video_Stream_0.mp4 -vf "settb=AVTB,setpts=N/TB" -fps_mode passthrough out-%03d.jpg
```